# Interactive SelecBox Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new in Shiny/R and I am having trouble to figure out the following:

I want to plot 2 `selectInput` on the `panel`. The first I would like to choose a state (for instance "Alabama"), and the second I would like to choose the cities that correspond to the state selected on the first panel.

This is the code:

```
TabCit <- read.csv(file= "~/Tab_Aux/Cities.csv", encoding = "UTF-8", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE, sep = ",")

ufname <- sort(as.vector(unique(TabCit[,8])))


ui <- fluidPage( 

  fluidRow(
    column(1), 
    column(2,selectInput(inputId =  "inufname", "variable", ufname ,  width = "100px")), 
    column(3,selectInput(inputId =  "incidname", "variable", uiOutput(“cituf”) ))
  )


)

server <- function(input,output) {

  output$cituf <- renderUI({ as.vector (sort(TabCit[TabCit[,8]==input$inufname,7]))}) 

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Sample of the data TabCit

"Code1,"Code2","Code3","Code4","Code5","Code6","City","State"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ABAETE","MG"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ABAETETUBA","PA"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ABATIA","PR"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ABELARDO LUZ","SC"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ABREU E LIMA","PE"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ACAILANDIA","MA"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ACARAU","CE"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ACAUA","PI"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ACRELANDIA","AC"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ACREUNA","GO"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ACU","RN"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ADAMANTINA","SP"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ADUSTINA","BA"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AFOGADOS DA INGAZEIRA","PE"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AFONSO BEZERRA","RN"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AFONSO CLAUDIO","ES"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AFRANIO","PE"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AGUA BOA","MT"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AGUA BRANCA","AL"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AGUA CLARA","MS"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AGUAI","SP"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AGUAS BELAS","PE"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AGUAS DE LINDOIA","SP"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AGUAS DE SAO PEDRO","SP"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AGUAS FORMOSAS","MG"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AGUAS LINDAS DE GOIAS","GO"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AGUDO","RS"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AGUDOS","SP"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","AIMORES","MG"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ALAGOA GRANDE","PB"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ALAGOINHAS","BA"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ALCANTARA","MA"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ALCOBACA","BA"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ALEGRE","ES"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ALEGRETE","RS"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ALEGRETE DO PIAUI","PI"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ALEM PARAIBA","MG"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ALENQUER","PA"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ALEXANDRIA","RN"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ALEXANIA","GO"

Comment: we don't have access to your data use dput() so we can run your script.

Comment: Code1,"Code2","Code3","Code4","Code5","Code6","City","State"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ABAETE","MG"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ABAETETUBA","PA"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ABATIA","PR"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ABELARDO LUZ","SC"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ABREU E LIMA","PE"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ACAILANDIA","MA"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ACARAU","CE"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ACAUA","PI"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ACRELANDIA","AC"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ACREUNA","GO"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ACU","RN"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ADAMANTINA","SP"
1,"1","1","1","1","1","ADUSTINA","BA"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a `uiOutput` here. It is only used when you want to dynamically generate a new or exchange an old UI Element.

In your case it suffices to use `observeEvent()` to catch updates to your first `selectInput` and the update the second one:

```
TabCit <- read.csv(file= "~/Tab_Aux/Cities.csv", encoding = "UTF-8", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE, sep = ",")

ufname <- sort(as.vector(unique(TabCit[,8])))

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( 

  fluidRow(
    column(1), 
    column(2,selectInput(inputId =  "inufname", "variable", ufname ,  width = "100px")), 
    column(3,selectInput(inputId =  "incidname", "variable", "" )) # Create an empty selectInput
  )


)

server <- function(input,output, session) { # include the session in your server

  #Here you use observeEvent to catch changes in the variable input$inufname
  #and update the content of your second selectInput
  observeEvent(input$inufname,
    updateSelectInput(session,inputId = "incidname", choices = as.vector(sort(TabCit[TabCit[,8]==input$inufname,7])))
  )

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```